# PowerApps Gallery Filter not working

Tags: filter, powerapp

I'm having another issue with my Filter formula. I have a gallery and I added a control (an icon) called FilterToggle which has a simple toggle action -- the OnSelect says

`UpdateContext({FilterToggle:!FilterToggle})`

This appears to work correctly as I have the color of the icon toggle on and off, based on an IF statement in the Color formula.

On my Gallery, my Items formula is set to:

```
If('FilterToggle'=false,
    {SortByColumns(
        Search(
            'Inbound RM Inspection',
            SearchBox.Text,
            "Title"
        ),
        "Title"
        )
    },
    {SortByColumns(
        Search(
            Filter('Inbound RM Inspection','INSP-NOW'=YES),
            SearchBox.Text,
            "Title"
        ),
        "Title"
        )
    }
)
```

The purpose is to include all Items if the FilterToggle is False and to include only those items who have INSP-NOW set to YES if FilterToggle is True.

Now all I get is an Invalid Argument Type.

Prior to adding this filter component, my Items formula was a just:

```
SortByColumns(
    Search(
        'Inbound RM Inspection',
        SearchBox.Text,
        "Title"
    ),
    "Title"
)
```

and it worked fine, so it's either the way I have the IF statement formatted, or the Filter command.

Thanks,
gpence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable shouldn't be in quotes, and the curly braces aren't needed. try:

```
If(FilterToggle=false,
SortByColumns(
    Search(
        'Inbound RM Inspection',
        SearchBox.Text,
        "Title"
    ),
    "Title"
    )
,
SortByColumns(
    Search(
        Filter('Inbound RM Inspection','INSP-NOW'.Value="YES"),
        SearchBox.Text,
        "Title"
    ),
    "Title"
    )
)
```

Edit: added .Value, as this is a choice field.

Comment: Well, Mike... that took away the red error flags, but now I get no data displayed -- either with the filter variable FilterToggle true or false! When I check the AppChecker it says the ItemNumberGallery.Items has an Invalid argument type... @Mike2500

Comment: The invalid argument type is probably the =YES, which should be in double-quotes: ="YES"

Comment: That didn't work either... and I notice an oddity which I can't explain. When I edit the Items formula, I expand the edit box down, but I noticed the Format Text and Remove Formatting options at the bottom are grayed out. If I copy and paste the previous formula (without the IF statement) then they are enabled. As someone's who worked with JS and CFML most recently, these formulas are... finicky.

Comment: The disabled format text button is caused by invalid syntax. For example, if I remove the last parenthesis, the same thing happens to me. One more item, if INSP-NOW is a sharepoint yes/no field, then it should actually be =true, not yes, though that shouldn't cause the other issues.

Comment: Yeah, it's a Choice field and I tried YES/NO, True/False and 0/1 and still no success yet.

Comment: I don't know why you're not getting proper error messages. When I tested that, I get a red squiggly under the equals sign between INSP-NOW and Yes. PowerApps doesn't handle choice fields all that well, and so this would need to be 'INSP-NOW'.Value="YES" (assuming this is a single select choice field, and not a multi-select field). Regarding the error messages, if you're not getting the red squiggly, perhaps try another browser. I'm using chrome.

Comment: I am getting the red squiggly under the equals sign as well, and a red dot on the App Check menu item. I meant that I was no longer getting a red dot on the canvas itself. Previously, when I modified the Items formula, there was a red circle at the upper left corner of the Gallery control which gave a longer error message. EDIT: and now the squiggly is gone, but still no data.

Comment: The red squiggly is important info, and I'd include that in the description next time. For now, that explains the behavior of why the whole thing wasn't working, as it was a syntax error. Add the .Value, the red squiggly should go away, the "format text" button should be enabled, and the whole thing should work.

Comment: That did it... sorry I omitted the squiggly info. Thanks for your help, Mike. You rock!